# Start/stop windows service in AWS ec2 instance3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, service

Is there anyway to restart the windows service installed in AWS Ec2 instance.
There is an option to restart ec2 instance

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

The AWS Console will only allow management of the EC2/server, not Windows services running within the server.